# Using RSpec to test for the queue is divided into two streams

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

Could you help me to test the queue. I'm new comer in rails and rspec.

```
it "the queue should be divided into two streams" do
     Queue.all
     expect(Queue.all.split(2)).to eq(2)
   end
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

What do you try to achieve with this test ? Because you only test the `split` ruby method here...

Anyway if you want to split an ActiveRecord result, you should use `in_groups_of(2)` method

Answer (score 0):

I found the way out myself after some attempts:

```
it "the queue should be divided into two streams", focus: true  do
    ap expected = [queue_prop_3_30.id, queue_prop_31_45.id]
    common_queue = CommonQueue.all
    queue_numbers = common_queue.map { |queue_number| queue_number.queue_id }
    ap actual = queue_numbers.uniq
    ap expect(expected).to eq(actual)
  end
```